# How to use Google/GSON to convert a JSON string into Java POJO?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following string:

```
{"account":{
    "username":"ikevin2222",
    "birthdate":"2017-01-31T09:37:44.000Z",
    "gender":true,
    "emailaddresses": [{
        "emailaddress":"aaa@bbb.com",
        "verificationcode":"AAAAAA",
        "isverified":false
    }]
}}
```

How do I use Google/GSON to convert it to Java POJO?

Comment: Have you tried this : `gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyClass.class)`?

Comment: Write a POJO corresponding to your JSON structure and invoke the method as specified by @Abubakkar in his comment

Comment: The "account" was causing some confusion, but it's been resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generate your POJO by using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ or by adding plugin in studio (https://github.com/Hexara/Json2Pojo)

now add dependencies `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'`:

> convert your json or string to POJO

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
POJOClass pojo = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), new TypeToken<POJOClass>() {}.getType());
```